# Custom filter extending UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Tags: java, spring-mvc, filter, spring-security

Am creating a simple spring-security project, where am trying to extend UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and print the username and password on the console.

Below is my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Sample Spring Project Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>application-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlets/application-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>application-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Spring-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:cap="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd ">

    <http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=1"
            default-target-url="/welcome.jsp" always-use-default-target="true" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp" />

        <custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"    ref="domainAuthenticationFilter" />
    </http>

      <beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.jsp"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="domainAuthenticationProvider"
        class="com.mydomain.security.AuthProvd"/>

    <beans:bean id="userService"
        class="com.mydomain.service.UserService"/>

    <beans:bean id="domainAuthenticationFilter"
        class="com.mydomain.security.AuthProvd">
        <beans:property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureUrl" value="/login.jsp?login_error=1" />
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.jsp" />
        <beans:property name="loginPage" value="/login.jsp" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="domainAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

With this, when I deploy my application, I get the below exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'parent'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#22': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'domainAuthenticationProvider' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'domainAuthenticationProvider' defined in class path resource [spring/spring-security.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager must be specified
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1090)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1900)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me fix the issue

Comment: `nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'domainAuthenticationProvider' defined in class path resource [spring/spring-security.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager must be specified` do you need to specify `authenticationManager` when creating your bean `domainAuthenticationProvider`?

Comment: Why are you even doing that with an extension? If the only thing to do is to log the username etc. use an `ApplicationListener` and listen for [`AuthenticationSuccessEvent`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/authentication/event/AuthenticationSuccessEvent.html) events. Doing that in a custom filter is way to complex and requires to much configuration